# It Is possible to use own django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

hi i am new to Django and i want use my own admin site instead of default Django admin site due to my site requirement, Django admin is very power full but i want my own so i can program thing my way, it is very irritating find and use the admin objects even for small change, for that need research and it is time consuming task.

please help me

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: Of course you can, the admin is just a bunch of views (very feature rich views at that). You can create your own views, what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: let me explain i am starting e commerce project and i want add category like cloth->men and i have also footwear->men and
database tbl category with
id  | catename | parent_id
so  when i am add product from admin there are i have category field there all category within that so if i want add product in cloth->men here i am not able to find men because footwear also have men category and i many category which i will add later and this project became more complicated so i not want djanog admin that's the main problem. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually it's very usual to create your own control panel instead of using the Django Admin, which could be sometimes a bit tedious to modify to get what you want.

You can modify the /admin/ URL in your urls.py and set your own view, but make sure you only allowed people with enough privileges to access it.